# finding similarities in rows for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to think of a way to efficiently accomplish this data wrangling problem in pandas.   Here is my pandas dataframe:

```
 brian steve joe tom
0   1    0   1   0
1   1    0   0   0
2   0    1   1   0
3   1    0   1   1
```

I essentially want to find who has a value of 1 in the same row and then count the number of rows where they both have 1's.  So, for instance, brian and joe are in the same row twice (row 0 and 3) so their score together would be 2.  The first way I thought about approach this was by creating dictionaries.  I thought I'd do something like {brian: 0, 1, 3} and then compare/count the similarities.  Couldn't get this to work as I had problem with multilevel indices.

I then thought possibility reshaping/melting the dataframe in order to solve the problem.

I was thinking a df that looks like this (showing snippet of row 1 essentially melted):

```
0   brian    steve   1   0
1   brian    joe     1   1
2   brian    tom     1   0
3   steve    brian   0   1
4   steve    joe     0   1
5   steve    tom     0   0
...
```

Am I thinking about this the right way?  I tried using a lot of different variations of pd.melt and couldn't get what I wanted.  Is there something simple I'm missing?  It's causing a lot of frustration trying to reshape the dataframe to what I want to solve the problem, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matrix multiplication should do, no? Or it's more complicated than that?

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]: 
   brian  steve  joe  tom
0      1      0    1    0
1      1      0    0    0
2      0      1    1    0
3      1      0    1    1

In [38]: df.T.dot(df)
Out[38]: 
       brian  steve  joe  tom
brian      3      0    2    1
steve      0      1    1    0
joe        2      1    3    1
tom        1      0    1    1
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks @exp1orer

```
In [40]: df2 = df.T.dot(df)

In [41]: df3 = df2.stack().reset_index()

In [42]: df3[df3.level_0 != df3.level_1]
Out[42]: 
   level_0 level_1  0
1    brian   steve  0
2    brian     joe  2
3    brian     tom  1
4    steve   brian  0
6    steve     joe  1
7    steve     tom  0
8      joe   brian  2
9      joe   steve  1
11     joe     tom  1
12     tom   brian  1
13     tom   steve  0
14     tom     joe  1
```

Comment: Nice! To match OP's desired output, you could then `stack`, `reset_index` on the names and then remove rows where the two names are the same.

Comment: this is really helpful, i was overthinking this completely it looks like